# How can i access ng-content components from parent?

Tags: angular

I am familiar with the concept of `@ContentChildren` but my case is somehow doesn't appear in Angular bible they even wrote this:

> Does not retrieve elements or directives that are in other components'
>   templates, since a component's template, is always a black box to its
>   ancestors.

i have this markup:

```
<layers>
 <layer></layer>
 <layer></layer>
</layers>
```

This is what iv'e been trying to do and i'm getting an empty list all the time:

```
import {
    AfterContentInit,
    ChangeDetectionStrategy,
    Component,
    ContentChildren,
    QueryList
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'layers',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class LayersComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChildren(LayerComponent) layers:QueryList<LayerComponent>;
    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        console.log(this.layers);
    }
}
```

A solution that did work for me to use a root service that injected to each layer and expose an API to register the current component instance into the service - but it makes things more complicated for me, thanks.

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: Well no - it works great in stackblitz - in my original project we work with angularjs combined with angular 8 so it may be the reason for this.

Comment: It should work. Here is a demo. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3gnme

The quote is talking about do not query elements in other component's templates. Did you define the `layers` component in `ng-template`?